# Process Builder Formula Question

Tags: formula, process-builder

I'm used to building process builders with conditions but this new Org that I'm in uses formulas.

I'm trying to make this criteria formula work:

```
       AND([Launch__c].RecordType.Name=Blue)
```

> Launch = Custom Object. Record Type name = "Blue". // need to check
>   record type

name

So I dont want the action to activate unless the record type is "Blue".

Thanks

Comment: what is your issue, is that formula working or not?

Comment: Is this correct?

 AND([Launch__c].RecordType.Name=Blue) 

Or is it something like:

 AND([Launch__c].RecordType.Name='Blue')

Comment: you should use like  `[Launch__c].RecordType.Name="Blue"

Comment: I'm getting this Error: " The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra AND"

 ISCHANGED([Launch__c].Stage__c) 
 AND[Launch__c].RecordType.Name='Blue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you added `AND` operator for one check only , AND operates must use at least 2 conditions, in your scenario 1) is `Stage__c` change check and 2nd record type name  check.
try this one

```
AND (
   ISCHANGED([Launch__c].Stage__c),
   [Launch__c].RecordType.Name='Blue'
)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you sir, I appreciate your knowledge and patience.

Comment: YW, i would recommend go through https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5  when you get a chance.

Comment: I also understand how "AND" works at the beginning now. Instead of between, by stating "AND" at the start, you're specifying that for everything after that to be AND. So this is awesome. TY

Comment: Thank you, I bookmarked that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case, the correct syntax would be

```
[Launch__c].RecordType.Name = 'Blue'
```

The string that is being comparing it to needs to be enclosed in 'quotes' so the compiler knows that it is a string.

I suggest you use do this [Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) about formula fields

[The Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) is useful as it gives a complete overview with examples (such as how to use the AND() formula.)

:)

Comment: I'm getting this Error: " The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra AND"

 ISCHANGED([Launch__c].Stage__c) 
 AND[Launch__c].RecordType.Name='Blue'

Comment: To use the AND() formula properly you need to add your conditions seperated by a comma. You need write: 
AND(
ISCHANGED([Launch__c].Stage__c),
[Launch__c].RecordType.Name = 'Blue'
)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your knowledge and patience.